# Extract val attribute from li

Tags: javascript

Inputting this command into chrome's consle:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[69];
```

I get the following output:

```
<li val="169244288">NoOneRuleZ</li>
```

I am trying to extract the val attribute. I've tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[69].value;
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[69].valueName;
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[69].val;
```

value gives me 0 and valueName and val give me undefined.

Comment: It's not valid HTML for an `<li>` element to have a "val" attribute. If you want to add non-standard attributes, use names like "data-val", which *are* standardized in HTML5.

Comment: @Pointy: I wish I could change it.

Comment: Note that there is no standard *val* attribute for [LI elements](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-li-element), there is a [*value* attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value). You should not use non–standard attributes, to store data use either the [*class*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#classes) or [*data-*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#custom-data-attribute) attributes that are provided specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `getAttribute`:

`document.getElementsByTagName("li")[69].getAttribute("val");`

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery,

```
$('li').attr('val');
```

Comment: Question didn't ask for jQuery.

Comment: Never hurts to have multiple solutions.

Comment: @Barmar It asked for JavaScript; this is JavaScript using a popular library. The question didn't rule out jQuery. It's a perfectly valid answer. +1

Comment: It's perfectly irrelevant if OP isn't using jQuery.

Comment: if they're already using jQuery, a jQuery answer is fine. If they're not, and there's a simple answer using plain JS, it's silly to suggest that they load jQuery just for this.

Comment: also, this is jOveruse, as noted by @Barmar.

Comment: This is a Q and A site. Maybe the next guy to see this IS using jQuery. `<sigh>` When people miss their meds. Didn't know it was a stack no-no : There are just SO many...

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT**
Sorry, didn't read it right. You have to use `attributes` property.

**EDIT2**
It might look like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("li")[69].attributes[0].value
```

This will only work if your attribute is a first attribute of the node.

`nodeValue`

Here's some documentation:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml

Comment: Answers that are barely more than a link [are discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion). If the page 404s, for instance, your answer becomes useless and unclear. Provide the relevant information in your answer, if you can.